# Odd behaivour of clientWidth and offsetWidth, why do they return wrong values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to understand why the below code snippet returns the wrong value and it doesn't matter whether I use clientWidth or offsetWidth.

```
const imgSize = document.querySelector('.slides').children[0].offsetWidth;
console.log(imgSize);
```

What does matter is where I import my script though. I found out that it will only return the correct value when I import my script at the end of my body tag, in addition, I have to keep the defer attribute!

```
<script src="../source/js/myJS.js" defer></script>
```

If I would import this in my head it is not working.

The **oddest** thing is when I import my script in my head with the defer attribute, then I will get randomly two values (133px or 450px), but only 450 is correct. So where does this effect come from?

I will now past the relevant css in case it is needed to answer my question because I am not sure whether it will be:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Rochester';
  font-family: 'Open                            
#gen-info .container-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#gen-info .slides {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#gen-info img {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
}

#gen-info h3 {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0 40px 0;
}

#gen-info .current-heading {
  display: block;
}


.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index:2;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;

  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index:2;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.nextBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.prevBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I also have media queries but in none, is a width of 133px

Edit:

The Html

```
//head area

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Rochester&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/427c34389f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script src="../source/js/myJS.js" defer></script>

  </head>

// img area
<section id="gen-info">
<div class="container-carousel">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left prevBtn"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right nextBtn"></i>
                        <div class="slides">
                            <img src="../source/img/gen-info/information/WinterAlt.jpg" alt="outsideHous">
                            <img src="../source/img/gen-info/information/feldberg.jpg" alt="Feldberg">
                            <img src="../source/img/gen-info/information/bspWinter2.jpg" alt="winterTitisee">
                            <img src="../source/img/gen-info/information/bspWinter1.jpg" alt="snowTrecking">
                        </div>
                    </div>
</section>
```

```
//complete JS


const btnPrevList = document.querySelectorAll('.prevBtn');
const btnNextList = document.querySelectorAll('.nextBtn');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
const imgSize = document.querySelector('.slides').children[0].offsetWidth;
console.log(document.querySelector('.slides').children[0]);
console.log(imgSize);



const makeCloneSlides = (img, c) => {
  const lastClone = img[img.length - 1].cloneNode();
  const firstClone = img[0].cloneNode();
  lastClone.className = 'last-clone';
  firstClone.className = 'first-clone';
  slides[c].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', firstClone);
  slides[c].insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', lastClone);
};

const moveCarouselLeft = () => {
  console.log('left');
};

const moveCarouselRight = () => {
  console.log('right');
};

for (c = 0; c < slides.length; c++) {
  let img = document.querySelectorAll('.slides')[c].children;
  makeCloneSlides(img, c);
  slides[c].style.transform = 'translateX(' + -imgSize + 'px)';
}

for (c = 0; c < btnPrevList.length; c++) {
  btnPrevList[c].addEventListener('click', moveCarouselLeft);
}

for (c = 0; c < btnNextList.length; c++) {
  btnNextList[c].addEventListener('click', moveCarouselRight);
}
```

Comment: what is `document.querySelector('.slides').children[0]` ... i.e. is it an `<img>` when  the width is wrong?

Comment: it is both times an img (the same img)

Comment: so you `console.log(document.querySelector('.slides').children[0])` to confirm that at the time the code runs it is the same image, rather than relying on inspecting the DOM?

Comment: yes I console.log(document.querySelector('.slides').children[0]) that and refreshed my code once while script tag at the end of the body and once script tag in my head. I got one element and two widths. 
I also console.dir(document.querySelector('.slides').children[0]) to confirm the width.

Comment: ok, just thought there may be some other code that is manipulating the content of `.sildes`

Comment: can you try adding `display: inline-block` to `img {` selector (I'm guessing here by the way, without a minimal, complete and verifiable example that demostrates your issue you'll need a CSS guru to know what is going on - and CSS is not my strong point)

Comment: I mean could it be that js gets width before my file is completely rendered? Because it feels really wired for me that is working when I put my script at the end. I thought to defer tells the browser to get the file while rendering HTML, but waits till the html is rendered and then starts executing the script.

Comment: I don't think defer waits for images to complete loading - but you have style on your image tags which *should* take effect - that's the weird thing - one more question - which browser does this happen in, and have you tried a different browser

Comment: well my images are in a container which has ```display: flex;``` but wait I'll do it

Comment: ahh, see, this sort of detail may well be important

Comment: inline-block did not do the job. I have the issue in chrome wait need to download quickly another browser on this machine.

Comment: please don't put long bits of code in a comment - edit your question

Comment: I created a a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/p8CXDPJ0

Comment: @JaromandaX I paste also the code into my question.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I got a similar issue on chrome. In Firefox, everything works fine. I read the following link but did not get any insight on how to resolve the issue. Moreover, the issue is random. It never shows up in development but only during production. https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-cssom-view-1-20160317/#dom-element-clientwidth

Comment: Same question. any resolution?

Comment: It is kinda crazy how many people run into this issue. I still do not know an answer though. I think I just went with placing my script tag at the end of the body tag.